# Embedding a swf using fbml in a facebook app

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

I am using FBML to embed a swf file into my facebook application, but it shows the message that movie is not loaded. The piece of code that I am using for this is:

echo "
< fb:swf 
    imgstyle=\"border-width:3px; border-color:white;\" 
    swfsrc='apsolute url of the .swf in the server where I am hosting' 
    width='340'
    height='270'
    flashvars=''
    swfbgcolor='333333'
    wmode='opaque'
    />";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need your flash application to interact with Facebook, there's an easy workaround to your problem: http://anandnalya.com/2009/01/15/embedding-flash-object-in-facebook-apps-fbml/